# Javascript getMonth returning previous month after adding days

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am adding days in today date and getting timestamps in milliseconds.

```
  for(i=1;i<=shippingDays;i++){

      var result = new Date();
      result.setTime( result.getTime() + i * 86400000 );
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.getMonth()+'-'+result.getDate()+'-'+result.getFullYear());
      newDate = new Date(result.getMonth()+'-'+result.getDate()+'-'+result.getFullYear());
     console.log(newDate);
 };
```

The first console returns `Thu Apr 07 2016 18:34:33 GMT+0500 (PKT)` but later on `result.getMonth()` always returns previous month value. So the second console always returns `3-7-2016` and third console always returns `Mon Mar 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)`.

My ultimate goal is to get milliseconds of next days from `00:00:00`. Like today is `04-06-2016`. I want to get milliseconds timestamp of next few days. And time stamp should be calculated from start of that date, i.e, `00:00:00`

Can any body let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months from `Data.getMonth` are **zero** based (so January is 0, feb is 1, etc).

So if you want to use the month value to make a new date just add one.

Answer (score 2):

getMonth is zero based so 0=January, 1=February, 3=April etc. So the output of console.log is correct

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 1 to the getMonth() function.

Example:

```
console.log((result.getMonth() + 1)+'-'+result.getDate()+'-'+result.getFullYear());
```

Will return the correct month / date. It's because the getMonth function returns a value of 0 - 11 (0 for January and 11 for December)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp